# Names of files accessed by an application

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos, process

Any help with this problem would be fantastic. I appreciate all contributions!

Let us say I'm running a daemon that is observing the behaviour of the app that has keyboard focus. I have it's PID and process name. Is there any way I can see what files that application is accessing?

I'm programming in Objective-C, Cocoa and C.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have clarified. I want to be doing this programmatically from the daemon. Thanks

Comment: i don't think so.. you can know that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a command line tool called lsof that shows you every file that's open and what program has it open. You could look at its source, then do the same thing periodically.

I don't think you can intercept reads and writes, though—not without using DTrace, which requires root powers.

Comment: `strace` doesn't require `root` permissions and shows all file access

Comment: qrdl: That appears to require Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Activity Monitor (from /Applications/Utilities).

Pick your process - press the Inspect button.

Choose the Open Files and Ports tab.

Comment: Thanks! but that's not exactly what I was looking for. Check my edit.

Comment: OK - clearly, the answer is "Yes" because the Activity Monitor (and `lsof`) do it.  It is not as easy, though.  Have fun!

Comment: Right. I guess what you are saying, in an indirect way, is find the source code of the Activity Monitor and go from there. Sorry if I misunderstood :)

Comment: @Eric: more particularly, I was saying I'm not sure exactly how to do it.  However, the information can be retrieved - possibly only by suitably privileged programs (programs with root privileges).